# #powershell array with loop to check files exists

Tags: powershell

I'm looking for help to create a script to:
1- check if 3 files are located in a given directory
2- for the files that are older than the current date they will be moved to a archive directory and the start-proce3ss will call out a third-party process to run and create the files
3- for all missing files the script will start-process to run a third-party process to run and create files.

I am not familiar to array and the script I've been working on runs a IF method to validate every step so I've been thinking the Array would make it simpler.

```
    # script
$report = "C:\Reports"
$archive = "C:\Reports\Archive"
$scripts = "C:\Scripts"

# check 1.txt#
$file = "C:\Reports\1.txt"
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $file -Path Type Leaf)) {
    try {
        cd $scripts 
        start-process Third-party.bat
    }
catch {
}
}


# check 2.txt#
$file = "C:\Reports\2.txt"
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $file -Path Type Leaf)) {
    try {
        cd $scripts 
        start-process Third-party.bat
    }
catch {
}
}

# check 3.txt#
$file = "C:\Reports\3.txt"
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $file -Path Type Leaf)) {
    try {
        cd $scripts 
        start-process Third-party.bat
    }
catch {
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldnt be calling the Thrid-Party.bat only once if at least once of the files is older? As you have it right now, you may potentially call the third party program 3 times

Comment: Also, unless your intent is to run the batch file asynchronously, in a new window, invoke the batch file directly instead of using `Start-Process`: If it is located in the current dir: `.\Third-party.bat`; if it is in the path: just `Third-party.bat`. That also allows you to check the process exit code via `$LASTEXITCODE` later.